# Extracting Data from table and writing to a file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have a SQL Server DB from which I need to pull data and write it to a `|`-separated `.dat` file.

DB Name:    `AppleDB`

Tables : `ApplePhone` and `AppleGear`

Structure of table `ApplePhone`:

```
Id  Phone
1   6s
2   7s
```

Structure of table `AppleGear`:

```
Id  Gear
1   ear
2   watch
```

I need a script that extracts the information from the above 2 tables and writes it to 2 `|`-separated `.dat` files.

`ApplePhone.dat`:

```
Id|Phone
1|6s
2|7s
```

`AppleGear.dat`:

```
Id|Gear
1|ear
2|watch
```

The below code generates xls file,but I need to get .dat file with | delimited.

```
## ---------- Working with SQL Server ---------- ##

## - Get SQL Server Table data:
$SQLServer = 'myServer';
$Database = 'AppleDB';
$SqlQuery = @'
Select Id,Phone FROM [AppleDB].[dbo].[ApplePhone]
'@;

## - Connect to SQL Server using non-SMO class 'System.Data':
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection;
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = `
"Server = $SQLServer; Database = $Database; Integrated Security = True";

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

## - Extract and build the SQL data object '$DataSetTable':
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];
## ----------  Excel ---------- ##

## - Create an Excel Application instance:
$xlsObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application;

## - Create new Workbook and Sheet (Visible = 1 / 0 not visible)
$xlsObj.Visible = 0;
$xlsWb = $xlsobj.Workbooks.Add();
$xlsSh = $xlsWb.Worksheets.item(1);

## - Build the Excel column heading:
[Array] $getColumnNames = $DataSetTable.Columns | Select ColumnName;

## - Build column header:
[Int] $RowHeader = 1;
foreach ($ColH in $getColumnNames)
{
$xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader).font.bold = $true;
$xlsSh.Cells.item(1, $RowHeader) = $ColH.ColumnName;
$RowHeader++;
};

## - Adding the data start in row 2 column 1:
[Int] $rowData = 2;
[Int] $colData = 1;

foreach ($rec in $DataSetTable.Rows)
{
foreach ($Coln in $getColumnNames)
{
## - Next line convert cell to be text only:
$xlsSh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@";

## - Populating columns:
$xlsSh.Cells.Item($rowData, $colData) = `
$rec.$($Coln.ColumnName).ToString();
$ColData++;
};
$rowData++; $ColData = 1;
};

## - Adjusting columns in the Excel sheet:
$xlsRng = $xlsSH.usedRange;
$xlsRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

## ---------- Saving file and Terminating Excel Application ---------- ##

## - Saving Excel file - if the file exist do delete then save
$xlsFile = `
"C:\Temp\dbResults_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyymmddhhmmss")).xls";

if (Test-Path $xlsFile)
{
Remove-Item $xlsFile
$xlsObj.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsFile);
}
else
{
$xlsObj.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs($xlsFile);
};

## Quit Excel and Terminate Excel Application process:
$xlsObj.Quit(); (Get-Process Excel*) | foreach ($_) { $_.kill() };

## - End of Script - ##
```

I want to get both ApplePhone.dat and AppleGear.dat created with a single script.

Help me getting edited the code.

Comment: It is creating a ApplePhne.dat file but no data is present nor the table columns.

Comment: I am not able to get it exactly.

Comment: Please try to provide an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or as close as you can get to one.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 . I am totally new to scripting. Just started working.

Comment: @mklement0 i haven't found the solution yet. This is working code for exporting the result to xls file. I have edited my question.

Comment: Please take the advice to create an MCVE to heart - the process of creating one will help you understand your own problem better, presenting one makes it much more likely that you'll get the help you need, and future readers will benefit more too.